# Storm, Kafka and Zookeeper recommended hardware

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I would to deploy a big data system, I try with Storm, Kafka and Zookeeper but I don't have experience about hardware (RAM, CPU, HDD or SSD....). So could anyone give me the recommend, suggest, advice or give me some reference link or book to research about it.

Thank you,

Comment: It depends mainly on the expected workload. Can you provide some numbers?

Comment: Hi. This question is likely to be closed, or at least will probably not generate a lot of useful answers as there is no definitive answer for this, all answers are opinionated, no solutions are clearly wrong. It all depends on your usage - and even then all advices would be acceptable under some assumptions. Instead of asking a generic question, you should implement your application on your normal PC, then measure your performance and project how much CPU power / RAM you'll need.

Comment: There are some brief discussions on hardware for Kafka in the documentation: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#hwandos

Comment: Thank you, this link very useful for me, and could you give me some link about zookeeper or storm?